# How to get real path of my file?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, connection

I'm working on a web application using netbeans and MS Acces as my database, in my connection class I tried to get the path of my acces file (located inside my project) via the following command:

```
  File f = new File("softTech.accdb");
  String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

The problem is, as soon as I run the project and it tries to connect, when  trying to get the path, the system gives me a path inside the tomcat's paste

I need your help, don't know what to do
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are two points:

**First: MS Access is really the worst choice as a database for a Java web application.**

MS Access is a desktop database not made for using it at the server side.
The JDBC-ODBC bridge was never meant for production use and was removed in Java 8.
The alternate driver Ucanaccess is nice for data exchange scenarios with a MS Access database but it uses a pure Java database (HSQLDB) as a buffer and an emulation layer to avoid the use of the original Jet Engine. This alone is a performance nightmare.

So you should consider to use another database for your web application. There are plenty of alternatives like SQLite, Apache Derby or H2 as embedded database engines or MySQL, PostgreSQL as client-server database systems. All with dedicated JDBC driver support.

**Second: The database path or the connection shouldn't be hardcoded inside your web application.** You should configure a named datasource in your application server (e.g. Tomcat). And inside your web application you can access the datasource via JNDI.

Example: Configure the database connection factory in Tomcat:

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <Resource name="jdbc/EmployeeDB"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="dbusername"
            password="dbpassword"
            driverClassName="org.hsql.jdbcDriver"
            url="jdbc:HypersonicSQL:database"
            maxActive="8"
            maxIdle="4"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

Example: Access the datasource via JNDI:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)
  envCtx.lookup("jdbc/EmployeeDB");

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
... use this connection to access the database ...
conn.close();
```

The examples are part of the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources).

The benifit is, the web application only knows the logical database name. You can have multiple Tomcat installation, e.g. one for testing with a test database and one production. You can use the same WAR file for both installations. Each Tomcat has to be configured only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using servlets then following code should work.

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/yourFileName")
```

In case of normal java class, you can use

```
new File("yourFileName").getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: Can't I get it from a Java Class ? My conection is in a Java class I can't use getServletContext().getRealPath("/yourFileName")

Comment: Thank yout, but again, doing it only gives me the godammit path inside tomcat's paste :'(